# Order of async functions execution

Tags: javascript, promise

I am dealing with an old codebase and faced this situation where it's difficult for me to understand the order of execution after promises are resolved. I am more familiar with async/await syntax or with a chain of then-s, but not with this one. Here is the snippet:

```js
_loadCaseDetail: funciton (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel('db2');

  loadLatestDatasetVersion(oDataModel).then(function (datasetVersion) {
    // do something
  });

  loadCountries(oDataModel).then(function (countries) {
    // do something
  });

  numberOfRulesetChanges(oDataModel).then(function (elements) {
    // do something
  });

  return fireImplicitLock(caseUuid).then(function (lockData) {
    // do something
  }).then(function () {
    // do something
  })
}
```

`loadLatestDatasetVersion`, `loadCountries`, `numberOfRulesetChanges`, `fireImplicitLock` - all return promises

My question is: What would be the order in this case for all then-s that come after these promises?

Is it exactly sequential as it is or it's not and we can refactor it with say `Promise.all`?

Does it even need any refactoring?

Comment: This just calls the functions from top to bottom. Each does its job regardless of the others. `_loadCaseDetail` returns the Promise from `fireImplicitLock()`. If there are any dependencies between `loadLatestDatasetVersion`, `loadCountries`, `numberOfRulesetChanges` and `fireImplicitLock` and this works then it's just luck...

Comment: @Andreas thanks for answering, so all then-s will be also executed in the same top-down order in the browser?

Comment: No. Whoever is done with its job triggers its `.then()`. There's no specific order.

Comment: @Andreas I see, so if there's no coupled code in these ` then` block it should work fine I guess

Comment: Doesn't need refactoring so much as improving. Four promises are created, only one of which is returned. _loadCaseDetail's caller has a right to expect all asynchronous activity to be represented in the returned promise, not just part of it. Therefore use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to aggregate the four promises, and return the single Promise thus created.

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the order in this case for all then-s that come after these promises?

The `then` function will fire when the associated promise resolves. That's the point of asynchronous code. It goes away until it is ready to do the next thing.

> we can refactor it with say Promise.all

You could use `Promise.all` to wait until multiple promises are resolved before doing anything with the resulting values, but that would be inefficient unless the `then` function for `C` requires data from `A` or `B`.

Comment: thanks for anwsering @Quentin. So no priority given to the returned promise? Basically this is snippet is a collection of different stuff that might be resolved at different points in time

Comment: No. The promise is just a value you can return like any other. There's no special casing.

Comment: @Ren Yes, those promises don't have a specific order, they might resolve at different point in time.

Answer (score 1):

`loadLatestDatasetVersion`, `loadCountries`, `numberOfRulesetChanges`, `fireImplicitLock` - all return promises they will get inserted into Event loop one after another.

`then` part of promises will get executed once promises are resolved. Which promise's `then` will get executed depends upon the execution of the respective `promise`.

```
_loadCaseDetail: funciton (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel('db2');

  loadLatestDatasetVersion(oDataModel).then(function (datasetVersion) {
    // do something
  });

  loadCountries(oDataModel).then(function (countries) {
    // do something
  });

  numberOfRulesetChanges(oDataModel).then(function (elements) {
    // do something
  });

  return fireImplicitLock(caseUuid).then(function (lockData) {
    // do something
  }).then(function () {
    // do something
  })
}
```

`Promise.all` is like a gate where you can pass array of promises and it will resolve only after all the promises are resolved.

```
let p1 = Promise.resolve(loadLatestDatasetVersion(oDataModel));

let p2 = Promise.resolve(loadCountries(oDataModel));

let p3 = Promise.resolve(numberOfRulesetChanges(oDataModel));

let p4 = Promise.resolve( fireImplicitLock(caseUuid)

let finalPromise = Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4]);

finalPromise.then(([datasetVersion,countries,elements,lockData])=>{

    // do something here with datasetVersion, countries, elements, lockData you have all the params cause all the promises are resolved.

})
```

Same thing you can achieve using `Promise.all` like shown above.

[More about promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
return fireImplicitLock(caseUuid).then(function (lockData) {
    // do something
  }).then(function () {
    // do something
  })
```

Above line will not return any result from promises, it will return `Promise object` with its status `resolved/pending/rejected` and `value`.

Comment: _"Same thing you can achieve using `Promise.all`"_ - `fireImplicitLock()` doesn't wait for one of the "previous" functions. Why should OP then use `Promise.all()`?

Comment: the `return` statement is misleading there cause it's not returning any value which will be useful. Its returning Promise object. That's why I thought OP has added it without knowing what it will return. Yes you are correct @Andreas return will not wait till any of the promises to resolve.